# can't get correct arguments when use awk command in a defined function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

There is a version.h file in project, like this:

```
#ifndef _VERSION_H_
#define _VERSION_H_

#define PROJNAME "Uranium"
#define VERSION  "1.0.1"

#endif
```

And I want to print the project name and version when use make to compile the project.
So I added following makefile:

```
PROJNAME_KEYWORD = "PROJNAME"
VERSION_KEYWORD  = "VERSION"

define GetPropValue
  $(shell \
    awk '{ \
      split($$0, words, " "); \
      for (i in words) { \
        if (index(words[i], $$(1)) != 0) { \
          word = words[i + 1]; \
          gsub("\"", "", word); \
          print word; \
          break; \
        } \
      } \
    }' version.h \
  )
endef

ifndef PROJNAME
  PROJNAME = $(call GetPropValue, $(PROJNAME_KEYWORD))
endif

ifndef VERSION
  VERSION = $(call GetPropValue, $(VERSION_KEYWORD))
endif
```

it's expected to have this:

```
PROJNAME = Uranium
VERSION = 1.0.1
```

But actually I got this,

```
PROJNAME=_VERSION_H_ _VERSION_H_ PROJNAME VERSION
VERSION=_VERSION_H_ _VERSION_H_ PROJNAME VERSION
```

After some debugging process, I found $$(1) in

```
if (index(words[i], $$(1)) != 0) {
```

line is incorrect,
when I replaced $$(1) with "PROJNAME",
I can get right result,

```
PROJNAME = Uranium
```

$$(1) should be arguments, like $(PROJNAME_KEYWORD) from

```
$(call GetPropValue, $(PROJNAME_KEYWORD))
```

So in this case, how to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**

Since you want to obtain data about macro definitions recorded in a C header file, the most natural tool to apply to the job would be the C preprocessor.  So how about skipping the user-defined function altogether, and going with

```
PROJNAME = $(shell echo PROJNAME | cat version.h - | cpp -P | tr -d '"')
```

**Explanation**

You are already assuming GNU's version of `make`., and its `$(shell)` function in particular.  `$(shell)` executes a shell command and evaluates to the contents of the command's standard output.  In this case, the command executed determines the definition of a preprocessor macro defined in `version.h` by

- concatenating the contents of `version.h` with a line containing the bare macro name, and
- piping the result into the preprocessor.  The `-P` option to the preprocessor suppresses generation of extra output, such as line-number indicators.

The macro definition contains quotation marks that are not part of the value you say you want to assign to your `make` variable, so the preprocessor output is furthermore piped into `tr` to strip those.

**Demonstration**

Given this complete makefile ...

```
PROJNAME = $(shell echo PROJNAME | cat version.h - | cpp -P | tr -d '"')

demo:
    @echo '$(PROJNAME)'
```

... , and the `version.h` file presented in the question residing in the same directory, running `make` or `make demo` produces this output:

> Uranium

Comment: Some C preprocessors output a fair amount of chaff, though.

Comment: @tripleee, that's the point of the `-P` option, which serves exactly the purpose of producing output intended for downstream consumption by a program other than a C compiler.  But one could also run the output through `tail -n1` to select only the last line, which is virtually certain to be the one resulting from preprocessing the line containing only the macro name.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger, it's a perfect solution, cpp command is better.

Before using this, need to confirm that "version.h" have a blank line at the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another day,

```
if (index(words[i], $$(1)) != 0) { \
```

$$(1) is incorrect, should be replaced with $(1),

```
if (index(words[i], $(1)) != 0) { \
```

but this cause another problem,
there are lots of error happens when makefile have static check before running,

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near }
```

This means static check don't know $(1) it is, might replace with empty but I'm not sure,
to resolve this, add "" before $(1),
so it should be like this,

```
if (index(words[i], ""$(1)) != 0) { \
```

it's all right in static check, and $(1) will be replaced with argv[1] properly.